# Looking for Python module to do lat lon calculations

Tags: python, geoprocessing, coordinates

I'm looking for a Python module that can provide some / all of the following services using latitude/longitude to define points:

```
Distance between two points
Point in polygon 
Distance along a multi-point path 
Identifier of closest point from a dict of points with identifiers 
Distance from a point to each point in a dict containing points with identifiers
etc
```

You get the idea...  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [GDAL Python bindings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/). Examples on how to use it can you find [here](http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/).

For example you create points with lat/lon like this

```
from osgeo import ogr                   # first import the library
point1 = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
point1.AddPoint(13.381348,52.536273)    # Berlin

point2 = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
point2.AddPoint(11.557617,48.136767)    # Munich
```

[image]

Create a transformation from EPSG:4326 (lat/long) to EPSG:3035 (Projected coordinate system for Europe in meters)

```
inSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
inSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
outSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
outSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(3035)
coordTransform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(inSpatialRef, outSpatialRef)
```

Transform our points

```
point1.Transform(coordTransform)
>> POINT (4550348.379724434576929 3275002.535206703934819 0) 

point2.Transform(coordTransform)
>>POINT (4436977.705661337822676 2781579.793173507787287 0)
```

And get the distance like this

```
point1.Distance(point2)             # Distance in meter from Munich to Berlin
>>> 506279.480221                   # roughly 506 km
```

Or you can create a polygon

```
ring = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
ring.AddPoint(-23.378906,68.974164)     # North West Corner of Europe
ring.AddPoint(-23.378906,34.307144)     # South West Corner of Europe
ring.AddPoint(31.464844,34.307144)      # South East Corner of Europe
ring.AddPoint(31.464844,68.974164)      # North East Corner of Europe
ring.AddPoint(-23.378906,68.974164)     # North West Corner of Europe (to close to polygon)

polygon = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)  
polygon.AddGeometry(ring)               # rough bounding box around Europe
polygon.Transform(coordTransform)       # transform it
```

[image]

And check if the polygon contains the point

```
polygon.Contains(point1)                    # Does Europe contain Berlin?
>>> True                                    # It does ;)
```

[image]

And for the rest you can write functions to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks.  What are the units that are used in your examples?  Do I need to convert my lat/lon points to these units?  Or do I need to inform ogr that I'll be providing lat/lon data and it will take care of it?

Comment: Ah - I've discovered that the points are expressed as wkb - now I just need to figure out how to convert to from okb/lat lon

Comment: OGR doesn't do geometry on the globe, so it's a little more complicated than shown above. Coordinates first need to be projected into an appropriate 2D CRS.

Comment: I edited my answer a little bit regarding your comments. I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

GDAL/OGR should be enough for you.

http://www.gdal.org/ogr/classOGRGeometry.html